# How to split a single string into multiple columns in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I am getting data as a single string. For example, my one record looks like - `2020/01/01 "Anna Thomas" 21`.(Note: fields are space separated). I want them in a Kusto table with schema Date, Name, and Age. I read about first inserting them to a source table and then ingesting into Target Table using the update policy. But how will I parse this type of records (thought of using splitting the record based on single space but then the name also gets splitted)?

| Date | Name | age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020/01/01 | Anna Thomas | 21 |

Comment: Are all the fields quoted? Can you add an example for a line or more with datatable()?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the [`parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/parseoperator) operator:

```
let MyTable = datatable(str:string) [
    '2020-01-01 "Anna Thomas" 21',
    '2020-01-05 "Slavik Kusto" 32'
];
MyTable
| parse str with Timestamp:datetime ' "' Name:string '" ' Age:long
| project-away str
```

Output:

| Timestamp | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Anna Thomas | 21 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 | Slavik Kusto | 32 |

Note: I changed the `/` to `-` in your timestamps, in order for the string to comply with the [ISO 8601 datetime format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/scalar-data-types/datetime) that is required by Kusto. If you have no control over the input data, then you can do the replace as part of the Kusto query, like this:

```
let MyTable = datatable(str:string) [
    '2020/01/01 "Anna Thomas" 21',
    '2020/01/05 "Slavik Kusto" 32'
];
MyTable
| parse str with Timestamp:string ' "' Name:string '" ' Age:long
| extend Timestamp = todatetime(replace("/", "-", Timestamp))
| project-away str
```

Output:

| Timestamp | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.0000000 | Anna Thomas | 21 |
| 2020-01-05 00:00:00.0000000 | Slavik Kusto | 32 |